# Loop over a file and run a shell script

Tags: linux, shell, scripting, cron

I have a shell script in Linux:

```
#!/bin/bash
#This script is to import tables from mysql to hdfs
source /home/$USER/mysql/source.sh
[ $# -ne 1 ] && { echo "Usage : $0 table ";exit 1; }
table=$1
sqoop import --connect ${domain}:${port}/${database} \
             --username ${username} --password ${password}\
             --query "select * from ${table} where \$CONDITIONS" \
             -m 1 --as-parquetfile --hive-import --hive-database ${hivedatabase} \
             --hive-table ${table} --map-column-java Date=String \
             --target-dir /user/hive/warehouse/${hivedatabase}.db/${table}\
             --outdir /home/$USER/logs/outdir

echo "****************************************************"
```

This script takes table names as the argument. The table names are in a file called *tables.txt*.

The *source.sh* file contents:

```
domain=jdbc:mysql://XXXXXXXXX
port=3306
database=testing
username=xxxxxx
password=xxxxxxx
hivedatabase=testing
```

Now I want to schedule this script in parallel. What I want to do is schedule this script for 10 tables at a time. Like take the 1st 10 table names from *tables.txt* and then run this script. If the script is executed for a table then take the 11th table and so on...

Is it possible to do in `cron` jobs, or how can we achieve that.

Please suggest a best method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the purposes of this answer, let's assume your script is in a file named `load_data.sh`, your settings are in `settings.sh`, and your list of table names is in `tables.txt`.  Now you can run:

```
xargs --max-procs 10 -n 1 sh load_data.sh < tables.txt
```

Read the `xargs` man page for details; the `--max-procs` causes `xargs` to spawn up to 10 processes at a time, and it will pass a single table name to each invocation.

Comment: So You mean to say that I have to create as shell script with your code. And execute that shell script

Comment: @Active_user, Not necessarily, that `xargs` code would also work from the command line.

Comment: Right. I was not suggesting that you "create a shell script". I mean, you *could*, but I would typically just type something like this on the command line directly.

Comment: @larsks  Thank you it did work but a small question I would like to collect the console logs for the script load_data.sh but I am able to collect for xargs thing

Comment: I am not entirely sure what you mean, and the comments here may be the wrong place for an extended q & a.  You can redirect stdout from the above command (`... > logs.txt`) as with any command.  If you want anything more granular, put the logic in your `load_data.sh` script.